# pyspark blaze-AttributeError: 'DiGraph' object has no attribute 'edge'

Tags: pyspark, blaze

when I blaze a pandas.dataframe,it can output the columns normally! When I run  "traffic.head()", it can run normally! However,when I run "traffic.Stop_day" ,it indicated the AttributeError just like below:

```
import odo
traffic=bl.Data(df)
print(traffic.fields)
```

> ['Agency', 'SubAgency', 'Description', 'Location', 'Latitude', 'Longitude', 'Accident', 'Belts', 'Personal Injury', 'Property Damage', 'Fatal', 'Commercial License', 'HAZMAT', 'Commercial Vehicle', 'Alcohol', 'Work Zone', 'State', 'VehicleType', 'Year', 'Make', 'Model', 'Color', 'Violation Type', 'Charge', 'Article', 'Contributed To Accident', 'Race', 'Gender', 'Driver City', 'Driver State', 'DL State', 'Arrest Type', 'Geolocation', 'Stop_month', 'Stop_day', 'Stop_year', 'Stop_hour', 'Stop_min', 'Stop_sec']

```
traffic.Stop_day
```

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>   e:\software\python36\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py in
>   **call**(self, obj)
>       700                 type_pprinters=self.type_printers,
>       701                 deferred_pprinters=self.deferred_printers)
>   --> 702             printer.pretty(obj)
>       703             printer.flush()
>       704             return stream.getvalue()
>
> e:\software\python36\lib\site-packages\IPython\lib\pretty.py in
>   pretty(self, obj)
>       398                         if cls is not object \
>       399                                 and callable(cls.**dict**.get('**repr**')):
>   --> 400                             return _repr_pprint(obj, self, cycle)
>       401 
>       402             return _default_pprint(obj, self, cycle)
>
> e:\software\python36\lib\site-packages\IPython\lib\pretty.py in
>   _repr_pprint(obj, p, cycle)
>       693     """A pprint that just redirects to the normal repr function."""
>       694     # Find newlines and replace them with p.break_()
>   --> 695     output = repr(obj)
>       696     for idx,output_line in enumerate(output.splitlines()):
>       697         if idx:
>
> e:\software\python36\lib\site-packages\blaze\interactive.py in
>   _choose_repr(self)
>       440     else:
>       441         warnings.warn(_warning_msg, DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
>   --> 442         return expr_repr(self)
>       443 
>       444
>
> e:\software\python36\lib\site-packages\blaze\interactive.py in
>   expr_repr(expr, n)
>       358                              isscalar(expr.dshape.measure) or
>       359                              isinstance(expr.dshape.measure, Map))):
>   --> 360         return repr_tables(expr, 10)
>       361 
>       362     # Smallish arrays
>
> e:\software\python36\lib\site-packages\blaze\interactive.py in
>   repr_tables(expr, n)
>       240 
>       241 def repr_tables(expr, n=10):
>   --> 242     result = concrete_head(expr, n).rename(columns={None: ''})
>       243 
>       244     if isinstance(result, (DataFrame, Series)):
>
> e:\software\python36\lib\site-packages\blaze\interactive.py in
>   concrete_head(expr, n)
>       220         return odo(head, DataFrame)
>       221     else:
>   --> 222         df = odo(head, DataFrame)
>       223         df.columns = [expr._name]
>       224         return df
>
> e:\software\python36\lib\site-packages\odo\odo.py in odo(source,
>   target, **kwargs)
>        89     odo.append.append      - Add things onto existing things
>        90     """
>   ---> 91     return into(target, source, **kwargs)
>
> e:\software\python36\lib\site-packages\multipledispatch\dispatcher.py
>   in **call**(self, *args, **kwargs)
>       276             self._cache[types] = func
>       277         try:
>   --> 278             return func(*args, **kwargs)
>       279 
>       280         except MDNotImplementedError:
>
> e:\software\python36\lib\site-packages\blaze\interactive.py in into(a,
>   b, **kwargs)
>       404     result = compute(b, return_type='native', **kwargs)
>       405     kwargs['dshape'] = b.dshape
>   --> 406     return into(a, result, **kwargs)
>       407 
>       408
>
> e:\software\python36\lib\site-packages\multipledispatch\dispatcher.py
>   in **call**(self, *args, **kwargs)
>       276             self._cache[types] = func
>       277         try:
>   --> 278             return func(*args, **kwargs)
>       279 
>       280         except MDNotImplementedError:
>
> e:\software\python36\lib\site-packages\odo\into.py in wrapped(*args,
>   **kwargs)
>        41             raise TypeError('dshape argument is not an instance of DataShape')
>        42         kwargs['dshape'] = dshape
>   ---> 43         return f(*args, **kwargs)
>        44     return wrapped
>        45
>
> e:\software\python36\lib\site-packages\odo\into.py in into_type(a, b,
>   dshape, **kwargs)
>        51         if dshape is None:
>        52             dshape = discover(b)
>   ---> 53     return convert(a, b, dshape=dshape, **kwargs)
>        54 
>        55
>
> e:\software\python36\lib\site-packages\odo\core.py in **call**(self,
>   *args, **kwargs)
>        42 
>        43     def **call**(self, *args, **kwargs):
>   ---> 44         return _transform(self.graph, *args, **kwargs)
>        45 
>        46
>
> e:\software\python36\lib\site-packages\odo\core.py in
>   _transform(graph, target, source, excluded_edges, ooc_types, **kwargs)
>        55     pth = path(graph, type(source), target,
>        56                excluded_edges=excluded_edges,
>   ---> 57                ooc_types=ooc_types)
>        58     try:
>        59         for (A, B, f) in pth:
>
> e:\software\python36\lib\site-packages\odo\core.py in path(graph,
>   source, target, excluded_edges, ooc_types)
>        92         pth = nx.shortest_path(g, source=source, target=target, weight='cost')
>        93         result = [(src, tgt, graph.edge[src][tgt]['func'])
>   ---> 94                   for src, tgt in zip(pth, pth[1:])]
>        95     return result
>        96
>
> e:\software\python36\lib\site-packages\odo\core.py in (.0)
>        92         pth = nx.shortest_path(g, source=source, target=target, weight='cost')
>        93         result = [(src, tgt, graph.edge[src][tgt]['func'])
>   ---> 94                   for src, tgt in zip(pth, pth[1:])]
>        95     return result
>        96
>
> AttributeError: 'DiGraph' object has no attribute 'edge'
>
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>   e:\software\python36\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py in
>   **call**(self, obj)
>       343             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)
>       344             if method is not None:
>   --> 345                 return method()
>       346             return None
>       347         else:
>
> e:\software\python36\lib\site-packages\blaze\interactive.py in
>   _warning_repr_html(self)
>       448     else:
>       449         warnings.warn(_warning_msg, DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
>   --> 450         return to_html(self)
>       451 
>       452
>
> e:\software\python36\lib\site-packages\multipledispatch\dispatcher.py
>   in **call**(self, *args, **kwargs)
>       276             self._cache[types] = func
>       277         try:
>   --> 278             return func(*args, **kwargs)
>       279 
>       280         except MDNotImplementedError:
>
> e:\software\python36\lib\site-packages\blaze\interactive.py in
>   to_html(expr)
>       387     if not expr._resources() or ndim(expr) != 1:
>       388         return to_html(expr_repr(expr))
>   --> 389     return to_html(concrete_head(expr))
>       390 
>       391
>
> e:\software\python36\lib\site-packages\blaze\interactive.py in
>   concrete_head(expr, n)
>       220         return odo(head, DataFrame)
>       221     else:
>   --> 222         df = odo(head, DataFrame)
>       223         df.columns = [expr._name]
>       224         return df
>
> e:\software\python36\lib\site-packages\odo\odo.py in odo(source,
>   target, **kwargs)
>        89     odo.append.append      - Add things onto existing things
>        90     """
>   ---> 91     return into(target, source, **kwargs)
>
> e:\software\python36\lib\site-packages\multipledispatch\dispatcher.py
>   in **call**(self, *args, **kwargs)
>       276             self._cache[types] = func
>       277         try:
>   --> 278             return func(*args, **kwargs)
>       279 
>       280         except MDNotImplementedError:
>
> e:\software\python36\lib\site-packages\blaze\interactive.py in into(a,
>   b, **kwargs)
>       404     result = compute(b, return_type='native', **kwargs)
>       405     kwargs['dshape'] = b.dshape
>   --> 406     return into(a, result, **kwargs)
>       407 
>       408
>
> e:\software\python36\lib\site-packages\multipledispatch\dispatcher.py
>   in **call**(self, *args, **kwargs)
>       276             self._cache[types] = func
>       277         try:
>   --> 278             return func(*args, **kwargs)
>       279 
>       280         except MDNotImplementedError:
>
> e:\software\python36\lib\site-packages\odo\into.py in wrapped(*args,
>   **kwargs)
>        41             raise TypeError('dshape argument is not an instance of DataShape')
>        42         kwargs['dshape'] = dshape
>   ---> 43         return f(*args, **kwargs)
>        44     return wrapped
>        45
>
> e:\software\python36\lib\site-packages\odo\into.py in into_type(a, b,
>   dshape, **kwargs)
>        51         if dshape is None:
>        52             dshape = discover(b)
>   ---> 53     return convert(a, b, dshape=dshape, **kwargs)
>        54 
>        55
>
> e:\software\python36\lib\site-packages\odo\core.py in **call**(self,
>   *args, **kwargs)
>        42 
>        43     def **call**(self, *args, **kwargs):
>   ---> 44         return _transform(self.graph, *args, **kwargs)
>        45 
>        46
>
> e:\software\python36\lib\site-packages\odo\core.py in
>   _transform(graph, target, source, excluded_edges, ooc_types, **kwargs)
>        55     pth = path(graph, type(source), target,
>        56                excluded_edges=excluded_edges,
>   ---> 57                ooc_types=ooc_types)
>        58     try:
>        59         for (A, B, f) in pth:
>
> e:\software\python36\lib\site-packages\odo\core.py in path(graph,
>   source, target, excluded_edges, ooc_types)
>        92         pth = nx.shortest_path(g, source=source, target=target, weight='cost')
>        93         result = [(src, tgt, graph.edge[src][tgt]['func'])
>   ---> 94                   for src, tgt in zip(pth, pth[1:])]
>        95     return result
>        96
>
> e:\software\python36\lib\site-packages\odo\core.py in (.0)
>        92         pth = nx.shortest_path(g, source=source, target=target, weight='cost')
>        93         result = [(src, tgt, graph.edge[src][tgt]['func'])
>   ---> 94                   for src, tgt in zip(pth, pth[1:])]
>        95     return result
>        96
>
> AttributeError: 'DiGraph' object has no attribute 'edge'

So,what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Simply, use the command "traffic.data.Stop_year"! That's enough.